# How to fix the error that the provided javaHome seems to be invalid?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I updated android studio the day before yesterday and since then I have this error when I try to run my Dart code in my emulator:

```
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. 
I cannot find the java executable. 
Tried location: C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre\\bin\\java.exe
```

However my javascript is well installed, as shown in the following image I can see the Java path in the java configuration panel.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_351\bin\javaw.exe
```

[image]

Also I have this result in command prompt.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_351"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_351-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.351-b10, mixed mode)
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I didn't have the JAVA_HOME environment variable. I added this variable with the correct path.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_351
```

Then I went to the path variable and added the following path: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

In the following folder: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`

I had an empty jre folder, I deleted it and android studio recreated a working jre folder.